# Do all image assets in an iOS port of LIBGDX game need to be multiples of two?

Tags: ios, libgdx

I am writing an android game with Libgdx. I want the possibility to port it to iOS in the future. I read some comments that all image assets need to be sized in multiples of two for iOS. Is this true for all assets/textures and do the width and height need to be the same, ie: 256 X 256 or is 256 x 128 OK?

Comment: Yes, but powers of two, not just multiples. And you need to do this for Android anyway. Only some Androids support non-power-of-two and for the ones that do there is a performance hit. They do not need to have equal width and height.

Comment: Thanks @Tenfour04

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that iOS supports any size, as I never heard that there's a need to transform downloaded images to other sizes to show them.

I know for sure that I never encountered an Android phone that does not support any texture size. I had my game released with different texture sizes for a year without problems until I switched to using a TextureAtlas. That's what I would recommend you, too.

If you are using Scene2d.ui and a Skin, just use SkinComposer to create your TextureAtlas. If you don't use Scene2d.ui, you can use TexturePacker GUI.